# Авторасширяемый TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Мне нужно сделать авторасширяемый `Textblock`.

У меня есть текстблок в который автоматически приходит текст. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы текст не переносился когда он не помещается, а размер текстблока увеличился.

Я подумал как это сделать, в голове 2 варианта.

Так как я использую mvvm, у меня не много возможностей этого сделать.

1 Вариант. Сделать в `ViewModel` свойство ширины, и на основе свойства с текстом рассчитывать ширину, и вызывать `OnProperyChanged()`.(Но как мне кажется это нарушение mvvm, логика связанная с view не должна быть насколько я понимаю во ViewModel).

2. Вариант. Сделать `CodeBehind` на ивент, и в нем уже получив текст вычислять ширину и устанавливать. Правда я пока не нашел на какой, но надеюсь оно там есть.(Но тут тоже загвоздка, опять же насколько я знаю, код позади не стоит использовать).

Вопрос в чем, какой из этих подходов верный и какой стоит мне его использовать?
Если 2 вариант, то можете подсказать ивент?

Comment: Эм, он и так должен автоматически подстраиваться под размеры содержимого.

Comment: Даже вон проверил, сделал [такой набросок](https://pastebin.com/SFPGpLsY), ну и получил [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItNFu.gif), чем вам не `текст не переносился когда он не помещается, а размер текстблока увеличился.`? Так что, мне лично ваш вопрос совсем не ясен.

Comment: Все понял, мой косяк, спасибо за ответ

Comment: А вообще, код позади можно использовать, только для view?

Comment: Да без разницы в чем у вас и что, в WPF по умолчанию все подстраивается под контент, если только вы сами не ограничили им свободу, задав жесткие рамки, размеры. Вот вам как [доказательство](https://pastebin.com/GazZxegz), тот же пример, что и ранее, только `TextBlock` внутри `Border`, да и `TextBox` убрал вниз, чтоб не трогал размер. Что такое `код позади` в вашем понимание, что вы там собрались писать?

Comment: Код для View. Т.е есть MainView код позади MainView.cs. В некоторых ответах на вопросы, встречились реализации кода позади. Например сменить окно, или супер сложную анимацию сделать. В таких моментах можно писать в MainView.cs?

Comment: А когда хотите, вам не запрещают ведь это делать) В MVVM проекте главное соблюдать слои, а именно: Model - данные, обращение с данными, работа с устройствами, файлами и прочее; View - окна, со всеми стилями, контолами, шрифтами и прочим; ViewModel - связующий слой, то есть он берет данные из Model, делает свойства для привязки, обрабатывает команды и так далее. По доступности: View - не должен знать вообще про что либо, вот представьте, что его делает другой человек, не знакомый с вами, чисто дизайнер. VM - не должен знать про View. M - не должен знать про др. слои (тоже самодостаточный).

Comment: Исходя из этого, в классе того же окна вы можете писать все что угодно, но только, если это связано с View, с UI, не затрагивая каким-либо образом другие слои. Единственное, что допускается - абстракция, то есть можно сделать, к примеру закрытие окна через интерфейс, это от части, допускается, ведь вы не будете зависеть от других слоев, как и другие слои от View.

Comment: Можно. Главное - не зслезать во вьюмодель, ну только если биндингами. А вообще 99,9% вопросов решается в прямо XAML. То есть, если что-то в разметке не получается - этодалеко не значит, что оно невозможно. Изучайте проблемы тщательней.